# What do the values in "Running Services" mean?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, settings

When I go to following path

**Settings : Applications : Running Services**

I see:

**Other: 78MB in 4**

**Avail: 109MB + 58MB in 8**

What does above mean?

Specially, [78MB in 4], [109MB + 58MB] and [8]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, it breaks down into this:

- **Other:** This is RAM that is unavailable right now because it's in use by services that are actually running (it might be ones that can't be killed, in fact). Using your example, there's 78 MB of RAM in use by 4 processes, hence "78 in 4".
- **Avail:** The first number here is the amount of RAM that is completely free and not allocated to any process (the 109 MB in your example). The second number is allocated but the process is in a state where it can be deallocated. Thus, "58 MB in 8" means there are 8 processes that are currently holding 58 MB of memory, but they are paused/frozen in the background and that 58 MB can be reclaimed by the OS if an active process needs it.

Edit: As [Jake](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3249/jake-basile) pointed out in the comment below, you can find a description in [this entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html) on the Android Developers Blog (scroll all the way to the bottom).

Comment: More info available here, near the bottom of the post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html

Comment: @Jake: Thanks! I think that's the link I originally read this at but I couldn't find it when I wrote this.